# CakePHP Base Table View not Found

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Thanks in Advance,

When i run bellow Code its showing following error while i add a User.

**SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'bookstore.users' doesn't exist**

I have user Controller in `\src\Controller\Admin\UsersController.php`

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller\Admin;

use Cake\Core\Configure;
use Cake\Network\Exception\ForbiddenException;
use Cake\Network\Exception\NotFoundException;
use Cake\View\Exception\MissingTemplateException;
use Cake\Event\Event;

class UsersController extends AppController
{
    public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);
        $this->loadModel('Admin/Users');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->set('headerinfo', array('seoTitle' => 'Dash Board', 'pageTitle' => 'Dashboard', 'breadcrumbs' => null));
        $this->set('users', $this->Users->find('all'));
    }

    public function add()
    {
        $breadcrumbs = array(
            array('', 'Users')
        );
        $this->set('headerinfo', array('seoTitle' => 'Add User', 'pageTitle' => 'Add User', 'breadcrumbs' => null));

        $this->loadModel('Users');
        $user = $this->Users->newEntity();

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->getData());
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('User inserted successfully.'));
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'add']);
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add the user, please contact support'));
        }
        $this->set('user', $user);
    }
}
```

And Model for Users Table is in following file `\src\Model\Table\Admin\UsersTable.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Table\Admin;

use App\Model\Entity\Admin\User;
use Cake\ORM\Table;
use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\Routing\Router;
use Cake\Validation\Validator;

class UsersTable extends Table
{
    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('admin_users');
        $this->primaryKey('auID');
    }
}
```

And Model for User Table's Entity is in following file `\src\Model\Entity\Admin\User.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Entity\Admin;

use Cake\ORM\Entity;
use Cake\Auth\DefaultPasswordHasher;

class User extends Entity {

    protected $_accessible = [
        '*' => true,
        'auID' => false,
    ];

    protected function _setAuPass($password){
        return (new DefaultPasswordHasher)->hash($password);
    }
}
```

Table Structure:-

```
admin_users

Column  Type    Null    Default Comments    MIME
auID    int(11) No           
auName  varchar(75) No           
auPass  varchar(255)    No           
auFullName  varchar(75) No           
auStatus    varchar(2)  Yes     A   A=Active, I=Inactive     
createdOn   datetime    Yes     NULL         
modifiedOn  datetime    Yes     NULL         
Indexes
Keyname Type    Unique  Packed  Column  Cardinality Collation   Null    Comment
PRIMARY BTREE   Yes No  auID    1   A   No  
auName  BTREE   No  No  auName  1   A   No  
auStatus    BTREE   No  No  auStatus    1   A   Yes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are loading/accessing the model in the wrong way. While you can use slashes in the alias to match a subfolder structure, this will create a property with that exact name, ie including the slash.

Loading a model using an alias with special characters will require that you access the property via `{}`, like `$this->{'Admin/Users'}`, which is pretty ugly, and should better be avoided.

Also in your `add()` action you are using the `Users` alias, which will not look in the subfolder, and hence either pick up the wrong file, or none at all, causing an auto-table to be used (an instance of `\Cake\ORM\Table` instead of a concrete subclass thereof). Similarly the controllers model autoloading functionality will also look for `Users` by default.

So long story short, if you want to use `loadModel()`, then use its return value, either directly in your actions:

```
$Users = loadModel('Admin/Users');
```

or by passing it to a property, which you *could* do in `beforeFilter()` if you need that model in all actions:

```
$this->Users = loadModel('Admin/Users');
```